# Bizarre boolean evaluation in JavaScript (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a weird problem in some JavaScript code that's a part of one of my RoR projects. Here's the code:

```
alert(<%= params[:browse_view]%>)

<% if params[:browse_view] == true %>
  alert('Changing to browse view...')
  changeToBrowseView();
<% else %>
  alert('Changing to list view...')
  changeToListView();
<% end %>
```

What's happening is that the alert at the top will show false, but then the top portion of the *if* statement will run. This is going to be a remarkably stupid issue, but I have no idea what's going on...

Comment: Show us the generated JS. And why not just `<% if params[:browse_view] %>`?

Comment: Yeah -- that's what I had it as originally... but I was trying to fix this issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure `params[:browse_view]` is a `boolean` rather than a string?

I would take a look at the proven ways to parse string values to their corresponding boolean values:

[Parse a String to a Boolean in Ruby on Rails](http://jeffgardner.org/2011/08/04/rails-string-to-boolean-method/)

Comment: My thought as well - params by default are entirely strings, as I understand it.

Comment: Ugh -- yep, I think this is what I'm lookin' for. So what's the correct way to deal with this? Do you cast all of the params?

Comment: @aardvarkk - Updated the answer with a method to parse the string to a boolean value.

Comment: OK -- so are all parameters always strings? Is it bad to put something like `params[:browse_view] ||= true` in controller code?

Comment: Yes, they are. All communication between the client and the server is essentially done in string form, it's up to you to convert them. This can be a little subtle in Rails because mass assignment will automatically convert from strings to numbers and the like, but if you're directly using the params they're going to be strings.